# Есть ли функция, которая чистит текст от html но при этом сохраняет все переводы строк?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Переменная содержит текст формате html при выводе этой переменной в `textarea`, текст выводится вместе со всеми тегами, можно ли как то почистить текст от html но при этом сохранить переводы строк?

ну например заменить `<br>` на `\n` а `</p>` на `\n\n` понятно что есть регулярные выражения, которые в этом помогут, но может быть в php есть готовая функция похожая на то что я хочу

```
$message = trim(strip_tags($message, '<p><li><br>'));
$message = str_replace('<p>', "\n", $message);
$message = str_replace('</p>', "\n", $message);
$message = str_replace('<br>', "\n", $message);
$message = str_replace('<br />', "\n", $message);
$message = str_replace('</li>', "\n", $message);
$message = str_replace('<li>', '', $message);
```

---

```
$message = trim(strip_tags($message, '<p><li><br>'));
$message = str_replace('<p>', PHP_EOL, $message);
$message = str_replace('</p>', PHP_EOL, $message);
$message = str_replace('<br>', PHP_EOL, $message);
$message = str_replace('<br />', PHP_EOL, $message);
$message = str_replace('</li>', PHP_EOL, $message);
$message = str_replace('<li>', '', $message);
```

Не знаю какой вариант лучше и можно ли сократить?

Comment: думаю конкретно эти теги простым replace заменить, тут и регулярки не нужны. А остальные теги просто удалить `strip_tags()`

Comment: в html нет переводов строк. есть разрыв строки. форматирует текст браузер.

Comment: @Mike пишу вот так  $message = str_replace('<p>', \n, $message);
 $message = str_replace('</p>', \n, $message); но выдает ошибку, если \n взять в кавычки то он их просто по тексту расставить как обычный символ, что не так?

Comment: ну так для интерполяции \n в перевод каретки оно доложно быть в двойных кавычках. вам бы почитать что нибудь по основам php

Comment: http://www.php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?string

Comment: может нужно `<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars($message); ?></textarea>` ? или `<textarea name="text"><?php echo htmlentities($text)  ?></textarea>`

Comment: Главное тогда не забыть предварительно обычные переносы удалить.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = "<br />
<?php  ?> 
<p>str_replace</p>
can work<br>
<?=ghfghf?> with arrays
<li>too</li>
";
var_dump($message);
$stripped = trim(strip_tags($message, '<p><li><br>'));
//var_dump($stripped);
$res = str_replace(['<p>', '</p>', '<br>', '<br/>', '<br />', '<li>'],'\n', $stripped);
$result = str_replace(['</li>', '  '], '', $res);
var_dump($result);
```

Результат:

```
C:\wamp64\www\2017\17_03_02_str_replace_array\index.php:11:string '

     
    str_replace
    can work

     with arrays
    
        too
    
    ' (length=106)
C:\wamp64\www\2017\17_03_02_str_replace_array\index.php:16:string '\n

    \nstr_replace\n
    can work\n
     with arrays
    \n
        too
    ' (length=67)
```